# how to create splash screen for samsung tv application

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

how can i create a splash screen for samsung smart TV application.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple. In the index.html add some div with the splashscreen (include styling).

And on the background download data. After data loading display main app screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.

You just need to put a div tag in your index.htm:

```
<div id="splashscreen"></div>
```

In style.css add some properties like:

```
#spalshscreen{
 height: 720px; // Full height of the TV screen
 width: 1280px; // Full width of the TV screen
 background-image: url(...);
}
```

And than in Main.js using jQuery you can call show() and hide() functions on a div for given time with: setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds);

e.g

```
function splashHide() { $('splashscreen').hide(); $('container').show(); }

window.onLoad(){
 $('splashscrean').show();
 $('container').hide();    // Container holds all other div-s in the app 
 setTimeout(splashHide(), 3000); // This will call splachHide() after 3 seconds. 
 // After 3 seconds splashscreen div will not be visible, while container div will be
}
```

This is one way of doing this. You can think of another using two html files for example.

Answer (score 0):

Every application does retrieve/load some data before starting up. That's why we use splash screen (from dev. point of view).

But sadly, Samsung app don't allow us to modify the splash screen. It has its own splash screen with black background. It only allows user to modify the logo and name of our app.

But we can have a workaround for this. We can display a fake div with a loader, our preferred background and text displayed on it (faking it like a splash screen). And good point in this is we can retrieve and pre-load all the data that is required by our app in the very beginning and then show our main screen.

You can achive the above task by this:

**HTML:**

> ```
> <!-- Splash Screen -->
> <div id="divSplash" class="splash hide">
>     <div class="header">
>         <img src="app/images/splashlogo.png" style="height: 110px;" />
>     </div>
>     <div class="bodyText">
>         <div>Please wait, starting up...</div>
>         <p id="splMessage"></p>
>         <div class="ajax-spinner-bars">
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="footer">
>         <div>
>             <label class="appName"></label>
>         </div>
>         <div style="font-size: 26px;">
>             <label class="DBVersion"></label><label class="playerName dotdot"></label>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

**CSS:**

> ```
> .splash {
> position: fixed;
> top: 0px;
> background-image: url('../images/backdrop.png');
> background-size: 100% 100%;
> width: 100%;
> height: 100%;
> z-index: 1000;
> ```
>
> }

**JS:**
Perform all the task sync/async here with jquery promise and then hide the splash screen.

> ```
> jQuery.when(Main.getDeviceInfo()).then(function(status) {
>         jQuery("#divSplash").hide();
>         Main.start();
>     }, function(status) {
>         // Some error perform necessary steps.
>     });
> ```

Hope it will help you to some extend.